# Error: viewType "resourceTimelineDay" is not available. Please make sure you've loaded all neccessary plugins

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fullcalendar

```
import React from 'react'
import FullCalendar from '@fullcalendar/react'
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid'
import timeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/timegrid'
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction'
import resourceTimelinePlugin from '@fullcalendar/resource-common'
import './calendar.scss'

const TempCalendar = () => {
  

  return (
    <FullCalendar
      schedulerLicenseKey="CC-Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives"
      timeZone="UTC"
      plugins={[resourceTimelinePlugin]}
      headerToolbar={{
        left: 'today, prev,next',
        center: 'title',
        right:
          'resourceTimelineDay, resourceTimelineTenDay, resourceTimelineMonth, resourceTimelineYear',
      }}
      scrollTime="08:00"
      aspectRatio="1.5"
      initialView="resourceTimelineDay"
      views={{
        resourceTimelineFourDays: {
          type: 'resourceTimeline',
          duration: { days: 4 },
        },
        resourceTimelineDay: {
          buttonText: ':15 slots',
          slotDuration: '00:15',
        },
        resourceTimelineTenDay: {
          type: 'resourceTimeline',
          duration: { days: 10 },
          buttonText: '10 days',
        },
      }}
      events={[
        { title: 'event 1', date: '2021-01-01' },
        { title: 'event 2', date: '2021-01-02' },
      ]}
      editable="true"
      selectable
      resourceAreaHeaderContent="Rooms"
      resources="https://fullcalendar.io/demo-resources.json?with-nesting&with-colors"
 
    />
  )
}

export default TempCalendar
```

```
dependencies = [
  "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.30",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.14.0",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.11",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "^5.5.0",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^5.4.0",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^5.4.0",
    "@fullcalendar/react": "^5.4.0",
    "@fullcalendar/resource-common": "^5.5.0",
    "@fullcalendar/resource-daygrid": "^5.5.0",
    "@fullcalendar/resource-timegrid": "^5.5.0",
    "@fullcalendar/resource-timeline": "^5.5.0",
    "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^5.4.0",
    "@hunters/group-object": "^1.2.8",
  
]
```

Most of this code is from fullCalendar timeline demoes. [here](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/timeline-custom-view-demo) I don't know what is gone wrong with this.Even if i try other views it gives with the same error with their names. Maybe I'm missing something for these timeline view I looked for answers other places but i didn't find anything. Please help me out.

Comment: you've imported lots of plugins but then haven't declared them in your fullCalendar code. I don't tend to load plugins in this way, but from memory (although the documentation doesn't mention it) I think the timeline ones do actually require the daygrid (or timegrid, I forget) plugins to be available as well. Try that and see if it helps. Also if you want the editable and selectable features to work, you need to mention the interaction plugin in your fullCalendar options too.

Comment: I had the same issue and had to remove dayGridPlugin and timeGridPlugin as I suppose they don't work with the resourceTimelinePlugin

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading to v5.4.0 of fullcalendar (including all plugins) solved this for me. It's hardly a "fix," but it's an option.

The underlying problem is the same error seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65747728/typeerror-cannot-read-property-resourceareawidth-of-undefined-fullcalendar). This error causes it to not load.

Answer (score 0):

To fix it you need to `registerPlugins` inside of your module.

You can try use this code:

```
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';
import timeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/timegrid';
import listPlugin from '@fullcalendar/list';
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction';
import momentTimezonePlugin from '@fullcalendar/moment-timezone';

FullCalendarModule.registerPlugins([
  dayGridPlugin,
  timeGridPlugin,
  listPlugin,
  interactionPlugin,
  momentTimezonePlugin,
  ...
]);
```